# Django url template with query parameters

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to pass query parameters via my view into a link, but it escapes me on how to actually achieve this in a good way.

My template is as following:

```
<a class="link-button" href="{% url 'videos:index' %}?tag={{ tag }}&page={{ next }}">Next</a>
```

This returns what I want:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/videos/?tag=1&page=2
```

While this works, it's quite fragile, does not handle `None` values and there must be a better way of doing this.

I tried to pass this via the `url`template tag but it did not seem to be what I was looking for since it requires url config changes for path:

```
{% url 'videos:index' page=next tag=tag %}
```

Is there an actual way of doing this or a template tag I can use to get the parameters? I tried searching for this but it gave me a lot of old results and more path urls, like: `/videos/page-1/tag-1/` which I'm not looking for.

I was hoping to do something like:

```
<a href="{% url 'videos:index'}?{% params page=next tag=tag %}">Next</a>
```

Comment: There's no such tag built in, but there's nothing to stop you writing one.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Can't you use [`urlencode`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is **no builtin** support, but you can **add one yourself**. You can for example define the following template tag. We can for example construct files in boldface:

```
app/
    templatetags/
        __init__.py
        urlparams.py
```

Where in `urlparams.py`, we define:

```
from django import template
from urllib.parse import urlencode

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def urlparams(*_, **kwargs):
    safe_args = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None}
    if safe_args:
        return '?{}'.format(urlencode(safe_args))
    return ''
```

In the template, we can then load the template tag and then use it like with:

```
{% load urlparams %}

<a href="{% url 'videos:index'}{% urlparams page='1' tag='sometag' %}">Next</a>
```

Note that strictly speaking, the URL parameters can contain the *same* key multiple times. This is here *not* possible. So we can not generate *all possible* URL parameters, but this is usually quite rare, and in my opinion not a good idea in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, had to use `from urllib.parse import urlencode` instead though. Python 3.x

Comment: @Bjarte: thanks for the feedback. That is now updated (since Python-2.x will no longer be supported within 1.5 years anyway)[

Comment: note: it is important the directory is named exactly `templatetags`

Comment: @Flimm: this only encodes one parameter. Furthermore, note that keys can contain characters that should be escaped as well. Hence it does not solve a problem.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You do not need to pass `urlencode` when you are using literals for the param names, as in the original question. Furthermore, you can use `urlencode` for the param names if you are using a variable for the param name. See my answer.

Comment:  This should be a built in

Answer (score 2):

you can use `default template filter` and update your example

```
<a class="link-button" href="{% url 'videos:index' %}?tag={{ tag|default:'' }}&page={{ next|defaul:'' }}">Next</a>
```

output for empty tag and page is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/videos/?tag=&page=
```

but if you want to dont print None Tag in url you must your own template tag or filter. simply you can write this template filter

```
@register.filter
def print_query_param(value, key)
   if value and key:
       return "%s=%s&" % (key, value)
```

and you can use it as below

```
<a class="link-button" href="{% url 'videos:index' %}?{{ tag|print_query_param:'tag' }}{{ next|print_query_param:'page' }}">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Template tag `urlencode`

Use the template tag [`urlencode`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode):

```
<a href="example?tag={{ tag|urlencode }}&page={{ next|urlencode }}">example</a>
```

#### Small note:

<sub>Note that there is no need to pass the param names themselves through `urlencode`, since in this case they are literals. If the param names were not literals, you would need to, like this:</sub>

`<a href="example?{{ name1|urlencode }}={{ value1|urlencode }}&{{ name2|urlencode }}={{ value2|urlencode }}">example</a>`

Comment: This does not urlencodes the parameter names, which can contain non-allowed characters as well.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It is not needed in this case, since the literal `tag` and the literal `page` cannot contain non-allowed characters, since we know that the characters `t`, `a`, `g`, `p`, `g` and `e` are all allowed characters. See my edit.