# How to build django template GET request arguments?

Tags: python, django

Django version >= 2.0.0

for example.

in the `urls.py`, I have a register a view function:

`path('detail/<str:db_name>/<str:collection_name>', views.detail, name='detail')`

and in the django template, I want to use the `url` function to build this url:  `{% url 'detail' db_name collection_name %}`, this will product url: `/detail/db_name/collection`, but I want the url is `/detail/db_name/collection?per_page_count=15`.

so, How can I build the GET request arguments by `url`.

thanks.

Comment: A solution is `{% url 'detail' db_name collection_name %}?per_page_count=15`, but I dislike this ugly methods.

Comment: Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51377425/2696165