# Best way to parse a URL query string

Tags: python, string, http, webserver

What is the best way to parse data out of a URL query string (for instance, data appended to the URL by a form) in python?  My goal is to accept form data and display it on the same page.  I've researched several methods that aren't quite what I'm looking for.

I'm creating a simple web server with the goal of learning about sockets.  This web server won't be used for anything but testing purposes.

```
GET /?1pm=sample&2pm=&3pm=&4pm=&5pm= HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:50000/?1pm=sample&2pm=&3pm=&4pm=&5pm=
```

Comment: Are you looking to write the parsing from scratch, or what?

Comment: What's wrong with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349367/parse-an-http-request-authorization-header-with-python or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685217/parse-raw-http-headers.  You haven't given us enough info about what other approaches are lacking.  Do you have an example header or two?

Comment: Nothing is 'wrong' with either of these posts.  Based on the programming experiences I've head in the past, I'm inclined to do something similar like a regex expression in the second link.  However, I wanted to ask and see if there is a simpler way to do it since this is my first python program.

Comment: Looks to me like you're talking about URL query strings, not HTTP headers. You might want to update your question to reflect this.

Answer (score 112):

Here is an example using python3 `urllib.parse`:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
URL='https://someurl.com/with/query_string?i=main&mode=front&sid=12ab&enc=+Hello'
parsed_url = urlparse(URL)
parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
```

output:

```
{'i': ['main'], 'enc': [' Hello '], 'mode': ['front'], 'sid': ['12ab']}
```

Note for python2: `from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs`

SEE: https://pythonhosted.org/six/#module-six.moves.urllib.parse

Comment: And why are the values like this ```['value']``` ? ```dic['enc']``` gets ```['Hello']```  - how to get 'Hello'? with split?

Comment: @Suisse see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447391/ajax-why-jquery-replaces-with-a-space the values are in a list because multiple values can be encoded see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571145/urlencode-an-array-of-values hope it helps

Answer (score 54):

The urllib.parse module is your friend: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Check out [urllib.parse.parse_qs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) (parsing a query-string, i.e. form data sent to server by GET or form data posted by POST, at least for non-multipart data). There's also [cgi.FieldStorage](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html) for interpreting multipart-data.

For parsing the rest of an HTTP interaction, see [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html), which is the HTTP/1.1 protocol specification.

Comment: I'm not writing the script for him. He specifically asked how to parse query data, at least that's what I read between the lines, even though those are not actually HTTP headers. But I didn't bother commenting on that.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you should write the script for him, but urlparse is only a tiny piece of this puzzle.

Comment: For the amount of information he gave, that's all there is to say. Specifically, if you're actually referring to HTTP headers: is he using a webserver which actually allows you to get HTTP headers uninterpreted (via some stream)? Is he using WSGI (where HTTP-headers are interpreted by the framework)? Plain-old CGI, where you have to interpret the environment and hope for the best? Whatever.

Comment: urlparse looks like a great resource.  The header is pretty simple and I've added it to the original question.  As I'm sure you can guess, my initial idea is to parse the get line into an array of strings.

Comment: Are you trying to write a webserver? Or some form of packet inspection/inspector?

Comment: As posted this is a simple web server that serves a web page consisting of a form.  When the user clicks submit, the form inputs are appended to the URL.  My goal is to parse the appended url, retrieve what was entered into the form, and display it on the page.

Comment: Why not use a "proper" webserver to host your application? There's no need to reinvent the wheel (i.e., implement your own application server, which handles parsing the incoming request). Have you had a look at CherryPy or anything similar? I'm trying to discourage you, even as a pet/hobby project, to try to write anything resembling a web-server, HTTP/1.0+ are a PITA to implement correctly.

Comment: I'm only interested in writing my own, and finding the best way to parse a URL query string.

Comment: If it's just the URL-query-string to parse, check out the modules I referenced in the answer. If you need to parse the full HTTP client interaction/request, you're in for some reading of RFC2616 (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) which describes the HTTP protocol. There's nothing "premade" for this kind of parsing in the Python stdlib.

Comment: For Python 2, you're looking for `urlparse.parse_qs`.

Answer (score 31):

If you need unique key from query string, use `dict()` with `parse_qsl()`

```
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.urlparse('https://someurl.com/with/query_string?a=1&b=2&b=3').query
    a=1&b=2&b=3
urllib.parse.parse_qs('a=1&b=2&b=3');
    {'a': ['1'], 'b': ['2','3']}
urllib.parse.parse_qsl('a=1&b=2&b=3')
    [('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('b', '3')]
dict(urllib.parse.parse_qsl('a=1&b=2&b=3'))
    {'a': '1', 'b': '3'}
```

Comment: It's important to notice that the casting from tuple to dict result don't consider `b` to have two values, one which gets ignored. Wasn't aware of [`parse_qsl`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qsl), good addition.

Answer (score 8):

built into python 2.7

```
>>> from urlparse import parse_qs
>>> parse_qs("search=quint&tags=python")
{'search': ['quint'], 'tags': ['python']}
```

Answer (score 2):

only for one line quick prototyping CGI vars without imports, not the best obviously but could be useful.

```
agrs = dict(item.split('=') for item in env['QUERY_STRING'].split('&') if item)
```

Comment: This will break if any parameter in the query string is URL-encoded. "Manual parsing" of URLs is the source of many security issues.

Comment: indeed why the warning "only for prototyping" posted it to show case a quick parsing without any import

Comment: I wonder if every URL parser is a "manual parser"? At some point someone had to sit down and write it...

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this article](https://tkte.ch/articles/2024/03/15/parsing-urls-in-python.html), use [`can_ada`](https://github.com/TkTech/can_ada) to parse URLs in Python:

from their project:

```py
import can_ada
urlstring = "https://www.GOoglé.com/./path/../path2/"
url = can_ada.parse(urlstring)
# prints www.xn--googl-fsa.com, the correctly parsed domain name according
# to WHATWG
print(url.hostname)
# prints /path2/, which is the correctly parsed pathname according to WHATWG
print(url.pathname)

import urllib.parse
urlstring = "https://www.GOoglé.com/./path/../path2/"
url = urllib.parse.urlparse(urlstring)
# prints www.googlé.com
print(url.hostname)
# prints /./path/../path2/
print(url.path)
```