# RegEx changing positions in search string

Tags: python, regex

I have this string:

```
rf=hello&ur=bello&au=yello
```

However position changes randomly with each new line, e.g.

```
au=yello&rf=hello&ur=bello
```

What regular expression would be needed now to fetch all rf=(a-z)+ where au == yello?

Comment: No regex. Parse. Exactly how depends on your language. For PHP, try [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse-str), as this will allow you to simply check `if( $arr['au'] == "yellow") echo $arr['rf'];`

Comment: Aggree with above, you could use regex, but thats way more complex. You'd need lookbehinds, if available, or build crazy optional not-captured groups, etc. Could you tell us, which language you use? Maybe modify you question accordingly

Comment: Python of course. So what is more T efficient? One RegEx with LookBehind/LookAheads or Two Regex with an if-clause in my code like Niet the Dark Absol suggested?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113090/best-way-to-parse-a-url-query-string

Comment: Unfortunately my real world input string is a bit more complicated - http://regexr.com/39pib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex you can use:

```
(?=.*?(?:^|&)au=yello(?:&|$)).*?(?:^|&)rf=([^&]+)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sM7yP8/1)

Parameter `rf` value is available in captured group #1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if group is not an option.  (JS by example)

```
(rf=([a-z]+)(.+))*(au=yello)(.+)(rf=([a-z]+)(.+))*
```

it will check if rf=? is present before au=yello or if rf=? is present after.

Feel free to simplify parenthesis.