# Parsing URL with regex

Tags: python, regex, conditional-statements

I'm trying to combine if else inside my regular expression, basically if some patterns exists in the string, capture one pattern, if not, capture another.

The string is:
'https://www.searchpage.com/searchcompany.aspx?companyId=41490234&page=0&leftlink=true" and I want to extract staff around the '?"

So if '?' is detected inside the string, the regular expression should capture everything after the '?' mark; if not, then just capture from the beginning.

I used:`'(.*\?.*)?(\?.*&.*)|(^&.*)'`
But it didn't work...

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can guarantee that there won't be any other question marks later, you could use something like `r".*?\??([^?]+)"`.

Comment: thanks for reply. But this still captures the 'https://www.search..' part. But I actually want to capture it happens when there's no question mark detected..

Comment: Why not use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html)? It allows you to get all the parts of the URL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to parse a URL query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113090/best-way-to-parse-a-url-query-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex:

```
(^[^?]*$|(?<=\?).*)
```

captures:

- `^[^?]*$` everything, if there's no `?`, or
- `(?<=\?).*` everything after the `?`, if there is one

However, you should look into [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) (Python 3) or [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) (Python 2) if you're working with URLs.

Comment: yes some famous saying about regular expressions comes to mind here (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html):

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> parse_result = urlparse.urlparse('https://www.searchpage.com/searchcompany.aspx?
companyId=41490234&page=0&leftlink=true')

>>> parse_result
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.searchpage.com', 
path='/searchcompany.aspx', params='', 
query='companyId=41490234&page=0&leftlink=true', fragment='')

>>> urlparse.parse_qs(parse_result.query)
{'leftlink': ['true'], 'page': ['0'], 'companyId': ['41490234']}
```

The last line is a dictionary of key/value pairs.

Answer (score 4):

regex might not be the best solution to this problem ...why not just

`my_url.split("?",1)`

if that is truly all you wish to do

or as others have suggested

```
from urlparse import urlparse
print urlparse(my_url)
```

Comment: cause I want to parse and extract parts for not only url but also the query and the path. so there's url string as above, but also path string as '/company/Analytics/GetService' and also the query string as 'companyId=4343&type=0&page=11'