# Python ValueError: too many values to unpack for crawler

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, valueerror

I am trying to run a scraper I found online but receive a ValueError: too many values to unpack on this line of code

```
 k, v = piece.split("=")
```

This line is part of this function

```
def format_url(url):
# make sure URLs aren't relative, and strip unnecssary query args
u = urlparse(url)

scheme = u.scheme or "https"
host = u.netloc or "www.amazon.com"
path = u.path

if not u.query:
    query = ""
else:
    query = "?"
    for piece in u.query.split("&"):
        k, v = piece.split("=")
        if k in settings.allowed_params:
            query += "{k}={v}&".format(**locals())
    query = query[:-1]

return "{scheme}://{host}{path}{query}".format(**locals())
```

If you have any input it would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The error is stating that there are more than 2 values after splitting so it cannot accommodate it in 2 variables. There are more than one = in your query

Comment: Just add a `print piece` before that call and it will print out the offending piece. Without knowing what url you're trying to parse, we can't offer specific help.

Comment: Include the query here in your question if you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that **one of the `piece`s contains two or more `'='` characters**. In that case you thus return a list of three or more elements. And you cannot assign it to the two values.

You can solve that problem, by splitting **at most one `'='`** by adding an additional parameter to the `.split(..)` call:

```
k, v = piece.split("=",1)
```

But now we still do not have guarantees that there is an `'='` in the `piece` string anyway.

We can however use the `urllib.parse` module in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) (`urlparse` in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x)):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qsl

purl = urlparse(url)
quer = parse_qsl(purl.query)

for k,v in quer:
    # ...
    pass
```

Now we have decoded the query string as a list of *key-value* tuples we can process separately. I would advice to build up a URL with the `urllib` as well.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of parsing the urls yourself, you can use `urlparse.parse_qs` function:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> URL = 'https://someurl.com/with/query_string?i=main&mode=front&sid=12ab&enc=+Hello'
>>> parsed_url = urlparse(URL)
>>> parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
{'i': ['main'], 'enc': [' Hello '], 'mode': ['front'], 'sid': ['12ab']}
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39841923/304209))

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any basic debugging: what is `piece` at the problem point?  If it has more than a single `=` in the string, the `split` operation will return more than 2 values -- hence your error message.

If you want to split on only the *first* `=`, then use `index` to get the location, and grab the slices you need:

```
pos = piece.index('=')
k = piece[:pos]
v = piece[pos+1:]
```

Comment: Shorter and more readable than `.index` would be `.split('=', maxsplit=1)`.