# How to call a particular element with certain keywords from a list in python?

Tags: python, list, indexing, element

I want to break down an URL and extract the information I need. Breaking an URL was easy, but I'm not sure how to extract the information I need.

Below is the URL breaking part.
I want to extract the destination id part and save it in dest_id.
In the example URL below, it will be '1504033' (next to 'destination-id=')

```
url = 'https://www.hotels.com/search.do?resolved-location=CITY%3A1504033%3AUNKNOWN%3AUNKNOWN&destination-id=1504033&q-destination=Las%20Vegas,%20Nevada,%20United%20States%20of%20America&q-check-in=2019-10-12&q-check-out=2019-10-13&q-rooms=1&q-room-0-adults=2&q-room-0-children=0'
url_break = url.split('%')
```

I know how to call by index number, but it may not work all the time because that part can be anywhere instead of 5th index. (It can be 3rd or 4th)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to parse a URL query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113090/best-way-to-parse-a-url-query-string) / [URL query parameters to dict python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584545/url-query-parameters-to-dict-python/43628262)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not split the url yourself, use appropriate libraries:

```
url = 'https://www.hotels.com/search.do?resolved-location=CITY%3A1504033%3AUNKNOWN%3AUNKNOWN&destination-id=1504033&q-destination=Las%20Vegas,%20Nevada,%20United%20States%20of%20America&q-check-in=2019-10-12&q-check-out=2019-10-13&q-rooms=1&q-room-0-adults=2&q-room-0-children=0'

from urllib import parse

k = parse.urlsplit(url)
params = parse.parse_qs(k.query) 

print(params)
```

Output:

```
{'resolved-location': ['CITY:1504033:UNKNOWN:UNKNOWN'], 
 'destination-id': ['1504033'], 
 'q-destination': ['Las Vegas, Nevada, United States of America'], 
 'q-check-in': ['2019-10-12'], 'q-check-out': ['2019-10-13'], 
 'q-rooms': ['1'], 'q-room-0-adults': ['2'], 'q-room-0-children': ['0']}
```

and access the dictionary:

```
dest_id = params.get("destination-id")
```