# Python webscraping url split

Tags: python, url, split, screen-scraping

I like to split
this url:

https://ordbok.uib.no/perl/ordbok.cgi?startpos=1&ant_bokmaal=100&ant_nynorsk=5&antall_vise=1&OPP=+n1&ordbok=bokmaal&bokmaal=%2B&spraak=bokmaal

So it should be:

```
https://ordbok.uib.no/perl/ordbok.cgi?startpos=1&ant_bokmaal=
```

and

```
&ant_nynorsk=5&antall_vise=1&OPP=+n1&ordbok=bokmaal&bokmaal=%2B&spraak=bokmaal
```

because i lik to change the number `100` to come to the next page.

How can i have a variable in between there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to parse a URL query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113090/best-way-to-parse-a-url-query-string)

Comment: Can't imagine it's only about this single url, isn't it? If you want to split just this specfic url, you could just use `.split('100')` to get a list where the two elements are both of your desired outputs.

Comment: you can change order and put `&ant_bokmaal=` at the end of url and append number without spliting. Or use text formating or f-string to generate url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `format()` to pass variable in it.

```
def url(index):
 url="https://ordbok.uib.no/perl/ordbok.cgi?startpos=1&ant_bokmaal={}&ant_nynorsk=5&antall_vise=1&OPP=+n1&ordbok=bokmaal&bokmaal=%2B&spraak=bokmaal".format(index)
 print(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just this very specific replacement you can use the string replace function.

```
s="https://ordbok.uib.no/perl/ordbok.cgi?startpos=1&ant_bokmaal=100&ant_nynorsk=5&antall_vise=1&OPP=+n1&ordbok=bokmaal&bokmaal=%2B&spraak=bokmaal"
```

**Replace**:

```
s.replace("ant_bokmaal=100", "ant_bokmaal=111")
```

**Result**:

```
https://ordbok.uib.no/perl/ordbok.cgi?startpos=1&ant_bokmaal=111&ant_nynorsk=5&antall_vise=1&OPP=+n1&ordbok=bokmaal&bokmaal=%2B&spraak=bokmaal'
```

you can see that ant_bokmall changed to 111.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `re`, which is quicker, and more accurate:

```py
>>> url = "https://ordbok.uib.no/perl/ordbok.cgi?startpos=1&ant_bokmaal=100&ant_nynorsk=5&antall_vise=1&OPP=+n1&ordbok=bokmaal&bokmaal=%2B&spraak=bokmaal"
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=ant\_bokmaal\=)\d+', str(999), url)
'https://ordbok.uib.no/perl/ordbok.cgi?startpos=1&ant_bokmaal=999&ant_nynorsk=5&antall_vise=1&OPP=+n1&ordbok=bokmaal&bokmaal=%2B&spraak=bokmaal'
```