# Python get session key (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

how do i get following sessionkey with BeautifulSoup:

```
<a href=" https://website.com/login/logout.php?sesskey=Q3bAQgiGA2" class="dropdown-item menu-action" role="menuitem" data-title="logout" aria-labelledby="actionmenuaction-6">
```

The output should be: Q3bAQgiGA2

I tried following: `sesskey = soup.find('a', attrs={'href':'sesskey'}).get('sesskey=')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to parse a URL query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113090/best-way-to-parse-a-url-query-string)

Comment: @Julia hello, thank you. How do i get the url from the source code?

Comment: Using something like `element["href"]`, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex or simply split:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
session_key = soup.find('a').get('href') # in your case, find would do
print(session_key.split("sesskey=")[1])
```

Edit:

find()- It returns the result when the searched element is found in the doc.And the return type will be <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>.

find_all()- It returns all the matches (i.e) it scans the entire document and returns all the results and the return type will be <class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>

So if you use find_all, you have to treat the result as a set.

Comment: hmm i am getting a error: raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Did i do something wrong? (URL edited) rs=session.get('https://website.com/user/edit.php?id=4250&course=1')
soup=BeautifulSoup(rs.text, 'lxml') 
session_key=soup.find_all('a').get('href')
print(session_key.split("sesskey=")[1])

Comment: If you just have only a single href in your parsed file, find would do.
find_all will be needed in case you are parsing over multiple URLs and want sessions id's of them all. You will have to run a loop for the same.

Comment: Read more [here](https://linuxhint.com/python-beautifulsoup-tutorial-for-beginners/#:~:text=The%20find%20method%20searches%20for,a%20list%20of%20type%20bs4.)

Comment: For multiple urls, it would go like this:
`for sess in soup.find_all('a'): print(sess.get('href').split("sesskey=")[1])`

Comment: thank you but it still doesn't work. now i get this error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Can you share what are you trying to do?

Comment: Please note that your question had `sesskey` variable and you comment has `id` variable. So you will have to parse accordingly. You are probably using sesskey instead of id which is causing the list index error.