# Split url in url with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re, python-regex

i want to split url in embedded url

I've tried Regex, but couldn't do it.

full url

https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=https://www.adaletyayinevi.com.tr/image/catalog/icndekiler/9786056403903.pdf&embedded=true

the url i want

https://www.adaletyayinevi.com.tr/image/catalog/icndekiler/9786056403903.pdf

The url address i want may change. Can be for example as follows, but the https and pdf part are always the same

https://www.adaletyayinevi.com.tr/image/icindekiler/9786056403903.pdf

Comment: What have you tried until now and what is not working?

Comment: it would be better if you provide your regex too

Comment: Show what you tried - that is a prerequisite to get help here

Comment: i've tried regex rule, but i'm not good at. example `r = re.split("^https://www.adaletyayinevi.com.tr$pdf", url)`

Comment: Regex is a poor choice for this. Consider using urllib instead [Best way to parse a URL query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113090/best-way-to-parse-a-url-query-string). This would give you a dictionary mapping for direct and easy access.

Comment: if i use parse url, returned query `embedded=true&url=https://www.adaletyayinevi.com.tr/image/catalog/icndekiler/9786056403903.pdf&embedded=true`

Comment: You could use a regex that is expecting to be a parameter inside the URL, meaning that the url must have an `=` sign before it and must have an `&` or nothing after. Giving you the following regex:
`(?<==)http(s)?:\/\/[^&]*`